# Indesign Script no longer printing output in Extend Script

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, basil.js

My script runs fine but I don't see any output anymore in the javascript console.
It looks like InDesign is no longer linked to it. Also normally InDesign would start up ExtendScript Toolkit but it no longer doest that.

Is there a way to reenable that?

(I updated to CC 2015)

Comment: Did you play with the debugging levels? $.level = 2

Comment: In what way you try to output to the console? I use `$.write('something')` and it works fine.

Comment: Same thing for me OSX 10.11.1 InDesign 11.0.0.72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for me this worked:

Change the 'ExtendScript Toolkit CS6':

[image]

To the desired program:

[image]